# Get tkinter widget size in pixels

Tags: python, tkinter, size, pixel

If I define for example `tkinter.Button` widget with parameters `(width=10, height=1)`(in characters) and then I want to retrieve it's size in pixels, how do I do it?

EDIT:
I tried `widget.winfo_height()` and `widget.geometry()`, but all these functions return height defined in number of characters. I think it would be possible to create the same widget in a frame and then write `frame.winfo_height()` which would return size in pixels, but this is not so elegant solution.

Comment: before asking such a basic question you should do a little research. There are many questions on this site related to getting the width and height of widgets and windows.

Comment: But these questions aren´t about size in pixels..

Comment: `winfo_height` and `winfo_width` will always return the number of pixels. If you think it is not, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Bryan, this seems unfair.  If you call widget.winfo_height() when the widget is created, you just get '1'.  But if ypu call widget.update() first, it gives the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I do get the correct size when following the above procedures, but the results from this example really puzzles me:
from tkinter import *

```
root=Tk()

labelName = Label(root, text='label')
entryName = Entry(root, foreground='red')

labelName.update_idletasks()
entryName.update_idletasks()
wl = labelName.winfo_width()
we = entryName.winfo_width()
print('wl, we: ', we, wl)

wl = labelName.winfo_reqwidth()
we = entryName.winfo_reqwidth()

print('wl, we: ', we, wl)

entryName.insert(0, 'entry.................sajdALSKJDASKDjsc')

labelName.grid(row=0, column=0)
entryName.grid(row=0, column=1)

mainloop()
```

outputs ???:

wl, we:  1 1
wl, we:  124 31

Comment: Notice that using .winfo_width() results in 1 only and

Comment: Notice that using .winfo_width() results in 1 only and that .winfo_reqwidth() gives  correct answers (wl, we order switched) without the need to make an w.update()

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I figured it out. We must call `widget.update()` first before calling `widget.winfo_height()`.