# Tkinter window resize to fit content without touching

Tags: python, tkinter, window, resize, tk-toolkit

I have created an application that required to use the `place()` manager. I tried using `pack()` and `grid()` but after many tries and lots of effort it did not work for my goals. Since I use `relx=` and `rely=` almost all the time and I want to put my app on multiple OS's I need to have the window resize to fit all the widgets without them touching.

Is there a way to do this? Since many OS's and their updates change rendering the sizes of widgets changes greatly and I don't want the user to have to resize the window all the time. I want it to just fit as tightly as possible or get the minimum width and height to I can add some buffers. Is this possible? If not, is there a way to fix my app without having to rewrite everything?

**Note:**

I found something similar: [Get tkinter widget size in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495285/get-tkinter-widget-size-in-pixels), but I couldn't properly get it to work.

Comment: _"I have created an application that required to use the place() manager."_ - why does it require using `place`? Of the main choices (the others being `pack` and `grid`), this is the one that is most difficult to get the window to resize properly IMHO.

Comment: @BryanOakley & Martineau I didn't mean to be snide or rude. I apologize for that. I found something and added it as a note but might need some help with it

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. It's exceptionally rare for an app to _require_ `place`. Without seeing an example of the type of app you're building and the problems you had with `pack` or `grid` it's going to be impossible for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can use the `widget.winfo_height()`/`widget.winfo_width()` functions to get the minimum pixel sizes. Since the `window.geometry()` function  requires pixel sizes you can make two lists: one for width, and one for height. By adding the minimum amount of widgets you can get the desired size.

Code:

```py
height_widget_list = [main_label, main_notebook, the_terminal, quit_button, settings_button]
width_height_list = [commands_label, main_notebook, quit_button]
widget_list = [main_label, main_notebook, the_terminal, quit_button, settings_button, commands_label]
# Widgets must be updated for height and width to be taken
for widget in widget_list:
    widget.update()
height_required_list = []
width_required_list = []
# Collects data
for widget in height_widget_list:
    height_required_list.append(int(widget.winfo_height()))
for widget in width_height_list:
    width_required_list.append(int(widget.winfo_width()))
# Get height requirement
minimum_height = 0
for height in height_required_list:
    minimum_height += height
# Get width requirement
minimum_width = 0
for width in width_required_list:
    minimum_width += width
# Make window correct size make window require the correct sizing
window.geometry("{}x{}".format(minimum_width, minimum_height))
window.resizable(False, False)
```